# Data Connection attempts do not show the credentials page after incorrect authentication type

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I attempt to set up a Sharepoint data connection. I choose Microsoft-account as my authentication, but it doesn't work - resource forbidden exception.

It turns out I should have used Windows-account instead. However, when I try to set up the data connection from scratch again, it skips the credentials prompt and goes straight to "resource unavailable".

I've tried deleting the cache from Data Connection properties, closing and opening Excel, and restarting the workstation - no luck with any of them.

How can I force Excel to give me the credentials page when adding new data connections (even ones I've "tried" before)?

Comment: Select `Anonymous` if the SharePoint Server does not require any credentials or  Select `Windows` if the SharePoint Server requires your Windows credentials. Other is select `Organizational account` if the SharePoint Server requires organizational account credentials.

Comment: @RajeshS The problem in my question is that I don't get the option to select any credentials - it skips the credential screen and goes straight to attempting the connection (and I assume it tries to use the credential option I selected the first time). Deleting the connection and re-making it does not give me the credential screen.

Comment: ,, expect that you are using Power Query or what?

Comment: @RajeshS I'm using Sharepoint List from the data connection menu

Comment: I mean to ask that are you connecting Excel to SharePoint data via Power Query or for what purpose?

Comment: @RajeshS I don't understand this question in any manner that I haven't already answered. I use the wizard from Excel's menu, and I select "Sharepoint Online-list". Whether that creates a Power Query in the back-end is beyond me. The behavior I describe in my question happens regardless which option I choose, however - first data connection with any given URL, everything looks normal. Second time I try to use an URL, credentials prompt doesn't show up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98443/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-vegard).